# How to search float fields as text in elastic using QueryBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I ve document named **plan** that correspond plan entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plan")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "plan")
public class Plan extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable { 

@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text , fielddata = true)
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "current_price")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text , fielddata = true )
    private Float currentPrice;

 }
```

Here my method search implementation

```
    public Page<Plan> search(String query, Pageable pageable) {
    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQuery(queryStringQuery("*"+query+"*").defaultOperator(Operator.AND));
    nativeSearchQuery.setPageable(pageable);
    List<Plan> hits = elasticsearchTemplate
        .search(nativeSearchQuery, Plan.class)
        .map(SearchHit::getContent)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new PageImpl<>(hits, pageable, hits.size());
}
```

Name and Description are searchable but float field isn't .
Marking as FieldType.Float doesn't give expected result .

Comment: I'm curious why you would store a float value as `text`? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Similarly the `id` field should be of type keyword instead of `text` + `fielddata:true` (bad practice)

Comment: By default all fields are searchable because id field is indexed

Comment: Ok, but that's not my point, though, I'm just saying that it doesn't make sense for an ID string field to be mapped as `text`, it should be a keyword, because it doesn't/shouldn't need to be analyzed